# Dealing with NAs after running pivot_wider

Tags: r

I have a long dataframe that I want to make wide using `pivot_wider`:

```
library(tidyr)
example_data <- data.frame(
    name = c("bob", "bob", "dick", "dick", "harry", "harry"), 
    sport = c("baseball", "football", "hockey", "basketball", "football", "basketball")
)
pivot_wider(example_data, names_from = sport, values_from = sport)
```

This gives the expected result, but with lots of `NA`s

```
  name  baseball football hockey basketball
1 bob   baseball football NA     NA        
2 dick  NA       NA       hockey basketball
3 harry NA       football NA     basketball
```

I want to convert the sport names to `TRUE` (since the name of the sport is already indicated by the column name) and convert the `NA`s to `FALSE`, creating a dataframe like this:

```
   name baseball football hockey basketball
1   bob     TRUE     TRUE  FALSE      FALSE
2  dick    FALSE    FALSE   TRUE       TRUE
3 harry    FALSE     TRUE  FALSE       TRUE
```

I thought this code would do the trick, but it threw an error:

```
pivot_wider(
    example_data, 
    names_from = sport, 
    values_from = sport,
    values_fill = list(sport = FALSE),
    values_fn = list(sport = !is.na)
)
Error in !is.na : invalid argument type
```

The code below gets me the reverse of what I'm looking for, which I could then work to convert to the desired dataframe:

```
pivot_wider(
    example_data, 
    names_from = sport, 
    values_from = sport,
    values_fill = list(sport = TRUE),
    values_fn = list(sport = is.na)
)
```

Is there a way to get directly to the desired dataframe? And are there any tutorials for how to use the `values_fn` argument so I can figure out why `values_fn = list(sport = !is.na)` isn't working? Thanks.

Comment: You could try something like `dplyr::mutate_at(vars(-name), ~ ifelse(is.na(.), FALSE, TRUE))` after you change the data to wide format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to create a dummy column with `TRUE` values and then use `pivot_wider`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

example_data %>%
  mutate(val = TRUE) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = sport,values_from = val,values_fill = list(val = FALSE))


# A tibble: 3 x 5
#  name  baseball football hockey basketball
#  <fct> <lgl>    <lgl>    <lgl>  <lgl>     
#1 bob   TRUE     TRUE     FALSE  FALSE     
#2 dick  FALSE    FALSE    TRUE   TRUE      
#3 harry FALSE    TRUE     FALSE  TRUE
```